# Как добавить зависимость в cqtdeployer вручную?

Tags: qt

У меня есть Qt приложение, которое я собираю под Ubuntu, с помощью утилиты **cqtdeployer**. Я использую атрибут `qif` чтобы создать установщик `.run` . Когда я переношу его на другое устройство и устанавливаю свою программу, мне выдает ошибку `Failed to load platform plugin "xcb"` из-за чего приходится ставить зависимости вручную: `sudo apt-get install -y libdbus-1-3 libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb render-util0 libxcb-xinerama0 libxcb-xinput0 libxcb-xfixes0`. После этого всё запускается. Путем дебага, я установил, что виновата либа `libxcb-xinput0`. *Как "подснунуть" эту зависимость в cqtdeployer, чтобы не устанавливать вручную?*

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону сборки `deb` - пакета с указанием зависимостей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из [ответов](https://github.com/QuasarApp/CQtDeployer/issues/705#issuecomment-1223648834) репозитория CQtDeployer.

Воспользуйтесь опцией **extraLibs**

```bash
cqtdeployer ... -extraLibs "libxcb-xinput"
```

---

Если вы используете конфигурационный файл, то там это будет выглядеть так:

```json
{
    ...
    "extraLib": ["libxcb-xinput"],
    ...
}
```

Где **...** - это остальные ваши аргументы.